# Mysterious divisibility condition showing up in computation of determinant of certain sparse matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, divisibility, determinant

*Notation:* by the $d$'th diagonal of an $n \times n$ matrix $A$ I will denote the diagonal parallel to the main diagonal that starts in row 1, column $d$. I will extend this definition in the obvious way to non-positive values of $d$, e.g. the $1$'st diagonal is the main diagonal and the $0$'th diagonal is the one that runs from $A_{2, 1}$ to $A_{n, n-1}$.

Now consider the following $n \times n$ matrix $A$. Most entries are zero. Non-zero entries appear only on two diagonals: on the $0$th diagonal, all whose entries equal $-1$, and on the $d$'th diagonal for some $d \in \{1, \ldots, n\}$. The entries on the $d$'th diagonal I will denote $a_0, \ldots, a_{n-d}$ (read from top left to bottom right).

If you compute $\det A$ for a few examples you will notice something curious:

- If $d \not| n$ then $\det A = 0$
- If $d|n$ then $\det A = \prod_{d|k} a_k$

So divisibility by $d$ shows up twice. (Even if $d$ was never meant to stand for 'divisor' (but rather for 'diagonal').)

Examples:
$$\begin{vmatrix}
a_0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
-1 & a_1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & a_2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & a_3 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & a_4 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & a_5  \\
\end{vmatrix} = a_0a_1a_2a_3a_4a_5,
\begin{vmatrix}
0 & a_0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
-1 & 0 & a_1  & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 & a_2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & a_3 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & a_4 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0   \\
\end{vmatrix} = a_0a_2a_4,$$
$$\begin{vmatrix}
0 & 0 & a_0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
-1 & 0 & 0 & a_1  & 0 & 0  \\
0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & a_2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & a_3\\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0   \\
\end{vmatrix} = a_0a_3,
\begin{vmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & a_0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & a_1  & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & a_2 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 &0 & 0 & -1 & 0  \\
\end{vmatrix} = 0,$$
$$\begin{vmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & a_0 & 0 \\ 
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & a_1 \\
0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 &0 & 0 & -1 & 0  \\
\end{vmatrix} = 0,
\begin{vmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & a_0 \\ 
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 &0 & 0 & -1 & 0  \\
\end{vmatrix} = a_0.$$

I will sketch a non-informative proof of this fact below, but here I want to ask: **is there a conceptual explanation for the appearance of integer division in these determinants**, in terms of one of the geometric or combinatorial interpretations of determinant? (Even a proof by partioning the matrix into blocks would be interesting.)

For me the importance of the arithmetic properties of the indices came as a big surprise. After all they are only indices. It 'feels' weird that we can tell if the dimension of a vector space is a prime number by looking at the invertibility of certain geometric transformations of it. But maybe that is because I can only visualize low-dimensional  spaces anyway.

Also: are there attractive generalizations?

*Uninformative proof (sketch):* Let $A'$ consist of the last $n-d$ rows and the last $n-d$ columns of $A$. Then $A'$ is of the same type as $A$ but smaller, so, proceeding by induction, we may assume that the result holds for $A'$. (Here we use that $d|(n-d)$ if and only if $d|n$.)

Next we note that the first $d-1$ columns (if they exist) only contain one $-1$ and otherwise $0$'s while the first row only contains $a_0$ and otherwise $0$s. So applying Laplace expansion to the first $d-1$ columns and the first row reveals that $\det A = a_0 \cdot \det A'$ and the result follows.

**UPDATE:**
As an alternative to my proof above and Robert Israel's proof below one could also notice that this is a special case of the (less mysterious but more beautiful) observation in my newer question: [Is this determinant identity known?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1284192/101420). Although I would still be interested in an more geometric approach to these phenomena I am accepting Robert Israel's answer as to encourage future readers to extend any answer to this question they might have into an answer to the more general question [Is this determinant identity known?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1284192/101420).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $d=1$ it's trivial (the matrix is lower triangular, so the determinant is the product of the diagonal elements).  So let's suppose $d > 1$.
Think of what permutations $\sigma$ can have all the matrix elements $A_{i,\sigma(i)}$ nonzero (and therefore show up in the expansion of the determinant).   Each $\sigma(i)$ is either $i-1$ (to get a $-1$) or $i-1+d$ (to get $a_{i-1}$).  Thus in any case $\sigma(i) \equiv i - 1 \mod d$.
Thus
$$\sum_{i=1}^n (\sigma(i) - i) \equiv -n \mod d$$
But since $\sigma$ maps $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ one-to-one onto itself, the left side is $0$, i.e. $n$ must be divisible by $d$ in order to have any such permutations.

Now supposing $d \mid n$, say $n = d k$, what permutations do we get?  Split up the $n$ rows into their classes mod $d$.  First look at rows $1, 1+d, \ldots, 1+(k-1)d$.  In row $1$ there is only the one nonzero entry ($a_0$ in column $d$), so we must have $\sigma(1) = d$.  Then we can't have $\sigma(1+d) = d$ so we must have $\sigma(1+d) = 2d$, etc.  Thus 
$\sigma(1+jd) = (j+1)d$, $j=0 \ldots k-1$.  Thus we pick up the matrix elements $a_{jd}$, $j=0 \ldots k-1$.

Each of the other $d-1$ classes of rows includes one of the bottom $d-1$ rows, 
say row $n-i = dk-i$, $0 \le i \le d-2$,
which has only one nonzero entry ($-1$ in column $n-i-1$), so $\sigma(dk-i) = n-i-1$.  Then we can't have $\sigma(d(k-1)-i) = dk-i-1$, so $\sigma(d(k-1)-i) = d(k-1)-i-1$, etc.  Thus we pick up only matrix elements of $-1$ for all these classes.

The rest is simply a matter of counting the number of $-1$'s and the sign of the permutation to make sure we have $\prod_j a_{jd}$ rather than $-\prod_j a_{jd}$.