# Is this determinant identity known?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, determinant, set-partition

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix that is 'almost upper triangular' in the following sense: entries on and above the main diagonal can be whatever they want, entries on the diagonal just below the main diagonal all equal -1 and entries on even lower diagonals equal zero. For example:
$$\begin{pmatrix} 
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13}  & a_{14} \\ 
-1 & a_{22} & a_{23}  & a_{24} \\
0 & -1 & a_{33}  & a_{34} \\
0 & 0  & -1  & a_{44}
\end{pmatrix}$$

I accidentally found a very nice expression for the determinant of these matrices.

For $i \leq j$ in $\mathbb{N}$ let $[i, \ldots, j]$ denote the interval of successive integers starting at $i$ and ending at $j$. There are $2^{n-1}$ ways to partition the interval $[1, \ldots, n]$ into subintervals (e.g. $[1, 2, 3][4][5, \ldots, n]$ would be such a partition): for each of the $n-1$ comma's in $[1, \ldots, n]$ we can decide whether or not to replace it by a ']['.

Now in order to compute the determinant of matrix $A$ of the form above, all we need to do is the following:

- Write down the $2^{n-1}$ partitions of $[1, \ldots, n]$ into subintervals.
- In each partition replace each subinterval $[i, \ldots, j]$ with the matrix-entry $a_{ij}$ and interpret the resulting string of matrix entries as a product
- Sum all the $2^{n-1}$ terms. (No minus signs involved!)

The result is $\det A$.

Weird, huh? As a free bonus we note that the  [determinant expression for the complete Bell polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_polynomials#Complete_Bell_polynomials)  can be computed in this way.

Since this identity is not terribly hard to prove my question is: is this known? But also a more conceptual explanation, perhaps linking the interval partitions here to the set partitions in the definition of Bell polynomial would be welcome.

**UPDATE:** Per request of Darij Grinberg I will give a proof and some easy applications to financial mathematics.

*Proof by induction on $n$:* Write $A_{ij}$ for the matrix obtained by crossing out row $i$ and column $j$ from $A$. We divide the partitions of the interval $[1, \ldots, n]$ into two types: those that end in $[n]$ (short-tailed) and those that end in $[i, \ldots, n]$ for some $i < n$ (long tailed). The long tailed partitions do not contain any intervals starting with $n$ or ending in $n-1$ so if we apply our three step process described above to this set only we obtain an expression in the elements of $A_{n, n-1}$ which (after the right renumberings) can be seen to equal $\det(A_{n, n-1})$ by the induction hypothesis.

When we apply our three step procedure to the short tailed partitions we obtain in an even more straightforward application of the induction hypothesis the number $a_{n,n} \cdot \det(A_{n, n})$.

So what remains to be shown is that $\det(A) = \det(A_{n, n-1}) + a_{n,n}\det(A_{n,n})$ but this is just Laplace's cofactor expansion formula for the determinant, applied to the last row of $A$.

*Interpretation of the determinant in case $A$ is constant along diagonals:* Suppose $A$ has $1$'s on the first (= main) and second (= the one just above) diagonal and $0$'s everywhere else (except for the $-1$'s on the zeroth diagonal of course) then the above states that $\det A$ equals the number of ways of tiling a path of length $n$ by tiles of length 1 and 2, which is well known to be the $n$'th Fibonacci number. By putting $1$'s on different diagonals we can similarly find determinant identities for the Tribonacci numbers or, more financially interesting, for the number of ways to pay an $n/100$-dollar bill with coins only.

Staying in the realm of money: if instead of just $0$'s and $1$'s we fill the diagonals with numbers from the real interval $[0, 1]$ (just one number repeated over and over per diagonal) the above count turns into a probability. For instance if we take $n= 40$, put $0$'s in the main diagonal, $1/12$'s in the second diagonal, $1/6$ in the third diagonal etc, upto $0$'s in diagonals 13 to 40, the determinant of $A$ will give us the probability of landing exactly on Go (rather than just passing it) after one round trip in a game of Monopoly.

*What I would be really interested in* are interpretations of these determinants in case the entries on each diagonal are not constant (but follow some other pattern enabling the interpretation).

Comment: Is this equality (4) in https://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/ahlswede/pub/tamm/hessen.ps ? Either way, the world will be a better place if you write up your proof and maybe expose some of the applications. Good job finding this formula!

Comment: Such matrices are called [upper Hessenberg matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessenberg_matrix).  Provided the first subdiagonal entries are nonzero, they may be normalized to $-1$ entries as you have done, with predictable effect on the matrix determinant as a whole.  You may find Milan Janjic's 2010 paper [Hessenberg Matrices and Integer Sequences](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL13/Janjic/janjic33.pdf) has similar results to yours.

Comment: Nice work on the post, Vincent! These applications to financial mathematics are actually applications to combinatorics, though.

Comment: I know, the mention of money is just click bait...

Comment: In my case it was almost anti-click bait.

Comment: I think the general consensus is that it might be touched upon in past papers, but write a paper on it anyways, because you might just be introducing new ideas!

Comment: It sort of reminds me the immanant. It could be a relation between characters of $S_n$ which reflects on the determinant calculation. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immanant_of_a_matrix

Answer (score 1):

Here is one easy interpretation for nonconstant entries on the first subdiagonal. Substituting $-a_{21},-a_{32},\dots,-a_{n,n-1}$ in place of the $-1$'s yields a weighted count, where each edge $(i,i+1)$ on the path from $1$ to $n$ has weight $a_{i+1,i}$, and the weight of the subpath from $i$ to $j$ is the product of the weights of its edges, $\prod_{k=i}^{j-1}{a_{i+1,i}}$. This is useful, for example, if there are multiple edges between successive vertices.